# windows versus linux std::getline string

Tags: linux, xml-parsing, g++, getline

I have an xml file that I want to extract some specific fields from

Sample test file

```
<ScheduleTask ID="ZmwnBtczlnYOBLyK" Code="000-000.0.0.0" Name="SETTLEMENT.BRIDGE" ParentSummaryTaskID="">
    <Quantities>
        <STQuantity MethodID="416" RecipeID=""/>
    </Quantities>
    <Timings>
        <Timing LocationID="$$$$$&gt;C1&gt;NB" CompletionRate="1">
            <Planned Begin="2012-03-08T07:14:57" End="2012-03-28T07:14:57"/>
            <Actual Begin="2012-03-31T06:00:00" End="2012-05-01T14:00:00"/>
        </Timing>
        <Timing LocationID="$$$$$&gt;C1&gt;SB" CompletionRate="0">
            <Planned Begin="2012-12-04T06:07:29" End="2012-12-24T06:07:29"/>
            <Forecast Begin="2013-04-18T09:16:37" End="2013-06-04T12:06:02"/>
        </Timing>
    </Timings>
    </ScheduleTask>
```

So, I have this function that looks for a line with /ScheduleTask (includes the <)

```
//xml file into ontology
list<stack<string> > addWordsFromFile(string filename, int changeLevel)
{
    ifstream ontology;
    ontology.open(filename.c_str()); 
string ontTemp, line;

list<stack<string> > control_list;

while (true) {
    getline(ontology, line); //read line
    if (ontology.fail()) break; //boilerplate check for error
    line.erase(remove(line.begin(), line.end(), '\t'), line.end()); //remove tabs

    if(line == "</ScheduleTasks>") break; //check for end of document

        if(line == "</ScheduleTask>") {
        ontTemp.clear(); //clear memory
    }

    //look for activity
    if(line.substr(1, 15) == "ScheduleTask ID") {
        int i = 41;
        while (line[++i] != '"') {ontTemp += line[i]; }
    }

    if (ontTemp != "" ) {//ready to add
        stack<string> tempMem;

        tempMem.push(ontTemp);

        control_list.push_back(tempMem);
    }
}
ontology.close();
return control_list;
}
```

In windows this function works fine and the `/ScheduleTask` is found - in Linux it is not found, though other fields are found just fine with `if(line.substr(1, 15) == "ScheduleTask ID")`

compiled with VisualStudio 2008 and g++

My question: 1) why doesn't this work in Linux and 2) how does it work?

Comment: I downloaded a hexadecimal reader, '</ScheduleTask>' after the previous 'carriage return' '0D' is '0A' 'line feed' then '09', '09', '09' 'horizontal tab', for '0A090909</ScheduleTask>'; I remove the horizontal tabs with 'line.erase(remove(line.begin(), line.end(), '\t'), line.end())' so is it the 0A line feed that Linux sees as still there for '0A</ScheduleTask>' != '</ScheduleTask>'

Comment: Also, the file is saved as ANSI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes down to the definition of the end of a line. Windows EOL is `\r\n` while Linux EOL is `\n`. So the line

```
</ScheduleTask>\r\n
```

comes back from `getline` as

`</ScheduleTask>` on Windows but `</ScheduleTask>\r` in Linux.

Comment: I will try if(line == "</ScheduleTask>" || line == "</ScheduleTask>\r") - this seems sketchy, but after reading wiki Newline the development of these codes was sketchy; Teletype... ?